# nginx catch all other locations than given

Tags: nginx

I have some locations on my server. I want to catch all other locations which users give via browser. How to to that? For example

```
 server {
     ...
     location /location1 {
              do something;
     }
     location /location2 {
              do something;
     }
     location /all_other_locations {
            return 301 http://www.google.de
     }
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

nginx's locations are prefix based (except regexp ones), so `location /` matches all requests unless more specific one matches.

```
server {
    location / {
        # catch all unless more specific location match
    }

    location /location1 {
        # do something
    }

    location /location2 {
        # do domething
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you wanted `/` to match something specific and then everything else be caught by something else?  Would you use wildcard matching then?

Comment: ah..  I think it may be to use `location = /`.  The explicit `/` request will be matched by it and everything else will go to `location /` unless something else matches.